# Pass Click Event to Function - JQuery Toggles Children in Unordered List

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working in ASPX, but this is just a straight JQuery call. I have a List item with one child list item inside. I am passing "this" to a function when a List Item is clicked. I am trying to get the child list to not expand when the parent is clicked. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
<ul>
    <li id="Menu1" class="collapsed"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="expandNavigation(this);">Faculty Resources</a>
        <ul id="Faculty_Res">
            <li>Archived Courses</li>
            <li>College List</li>
            <li>Current Courses</li>
            <li>Curriculum Outcomes</li>
            <li>EM Accreditation Information</li>
            <li>EM Competencies and Curricula</li>
            <li>EM Job Market Data</li>
            <li>Faculty Positions</li>
            <li id="Menu2" class="collapsed"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="expandNavigation(this);">Program Start Up Resources</a>
                <ul id="Faculty_Res_Prog_Startup">
                    <li>Needs Assessment</li>
                    <li>Proposal Examples</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Q&A</li>
            <li>Research</li>
            <li>Syllabi Examples</li>
            <li>Synergy Focus Group</li>
            <li>Synergy Webinar Slides</li>
            <li>Textbooks</li>
            <li>Webinars</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The "collapsed" class has a `display: none;`

Here is the JS using JQuery:

```
function expandNavigation(itemClicked) {
    $(itemClicked).next().toggle(1);
    itemClicked.stopPropagation();

    var parentItem = $(itemClicked).parent();

    if (parentItem.hasClass("expanded")) {
        parentItem.removeClass("expanded").addClass("collapsed");
    }
    else if (parentItem.hasClass("collapsed")) {
        parentItem.removeClass("collapsed").addClass("expanded");
    }   
}
```

Here is the CSS:

```
 `ul li.collapsed ul {
        display: none;
        padding-left:20px;
    }`
```

Comment: Note that you can replace that entire if/else if construct with a single line: `parentItem.toggleClass('expanded collapsed');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem with your code is that you are using *both* [`$.toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) and setting/unsetting a class to hide these elements yourself.

One option would be to use *only* the class approach, and to do so by using [`$.toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) rather than your own custom code:

```js
function expandNavigation(target) {
  $(target).parent().toggleClass('collapsed');
}
```

```css
ul li.collapsed ul {
  display: none;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="Menu1" class="collapsed"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="expandNavigation(this)">Faculty Resources</a>
    <ul id="Faculty_Res">
      <li>Archived Courses</li>
      <li>College List</li>
      <li>Current Courses</li>
      <li>Curriculum Outcomes</li>
      <li>EM Accreditation Information</li>
      <li>EM Competencies and Curricula</li>
      <li>EM Job Market Data</li>
      <li>Faculty Positions</li>
      <li id="Menu2" class="collapsed"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="expandNavigation(this)">Program Start Up Resources</a>
        <ul id="Faculty_Res_Prog_Startup">
          <li>Needs Assessment</li>
          <li>Proposal Examples</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Q&A</li>
      <li>Research</li>
      <li>Syllabi Examples</li>
      <li>Synergy Focus Group</li>
      <li>Synergy Webinar Slides</li>
      <li>Textbooks</li>
      <li>Webinars</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Note that your css is unnecessary, as [`$.toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) sets `display: none` manually

Comment: Nope, this is what I started with. I add the itemClicked.stopPropagation(); after researching this for a while.

Comment: Hamms: The toggle is not implemented on page load. Which is why I have to display:none.

Comment: in that case, use **just** the add/remove class and not `toggle`. As Rory mentioned, use `toggleClass` for that.

Comment: Still not going to work as I have to pass this to the function.

Comment: Thanks. Yes this works here, but not in my code. I'll look at it a bit more and see if I can get this to work. Thanks Hamms.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122942/discussion-between-hamms-and-mark-miller).

Answer (score 3):

The issue with your code is that you need to call `stopPropragation()` on the event that's raised, not the element which created the event.

Also note that you should use unobtrusive JS code to attach your event handlers. As you're using jQuery here's how to do that, along with how to shorten your logic using `toggleClass()`.

```js
$('.collapsed a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).next().toggle().parent().toggleClass('expanded collapsed');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="Menu1" class="collapsed">
    <a href="#">Faculty Resources</a>
    <ul id="Faculty_Res">
      <li>Archived Courses</li>
      <li>College List</li>
      <li>Current Courses</li>
      <li>Curriculum Outcomes</li>
      <li>EM Accreditation Information</li>
      <li>EM Competencies and Curricula</li>
      <li>EM Job Market Data</li>
      <li>Faculty Positions</li>
      <li id="Menu2" class="collapsed">
        <a href="#">Program Start Up Resources</a>
        <ul id="Faculty_Res_Prog_Startup">
          <li>Needs Assessment</li>
          <li>Proposal Examples</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Q&amp;A</li>
      <li>Research</li>
      <li>Syllabi Examples</li>
      <li>Synergy Focus Group</li>
      <li>Synergy Webinar Slides</li>
      <li>Textbooks</li>
      <li>Webinars</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't do it this way. I have to call the function.

Comment: Also, this doesn't work the way I am hoping to get it to work. All of the list elements are expanded on load with this. I want them all collapsed. Then when you click the top level / parent, the child should still be collapsed.

Comment: Thats only because i didnt add the CSS rule in as you added that to the question afterwards

Comment: Not at all. As I mentioned, the snippet was just missing the CSS you edited in to the question. I updated the answer to include and you can now see it working.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your are not calling `stopPropagation` on the event, but on the element. By passing the event, you can call stopPropagation on it.

Remove the `onclick` from the `a` element, add the class `toggle-control` so it looks like:

`<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="toggle-control">your text</a>`

And bind to the click event using jQuery:

```
$('.toggle-control').on('click', function (event) {
    var itemClicked = this;
    $(itemClicked).next().toggle(1);
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();

    var parentItem = $(itemClicked).parent();

    if (parentItem.hasClass("expanded")) {
        parentItem.removeClass("expanded").addClass("collapsed");
    }
    else if (parentItem.hasClass("collapsed")) {
        parentItem.removeClass("collapsed").addClass("expanded");
    }   
});
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.

Comment: No, still the same result after passing event.

Comment: And therein lies the problem. I have to pass it to the function.